# How to extract data of the multiple keys from the Response. in ELM

Tags: http, response, elm

I'm trying to extract data from the API response but In the decodeData I'm able to pass only one Decoded field, If I'm trying to pass multiple  fields then it makes an error

> Function `get` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
>
> ```
> Decode.Decoder a
> ```

```
    type Msg = 
  FindData |
  ReqCbk ( Result Http.Error String )

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of
    FindData -> 
      ( model, getData model.topic )

    ReqCbk ( Ok newData) ->
      ( { model | firstName = newData, err = ""}, Cmd.none )

    ReqCbk ( Err r ) ->
      ( { model | err = (toString r)}, Cmd.none )

getData : String -> Cmd Msg
getData topic =
  let
    url =
      "http://localhost:9191/"++topic++"/v1/xyz"

    request =
      Http.get url decodeData
  in
    Http.send ReqCbk request

decodeData : Decode.Decoder String
decodeData = 
   Decode.field "firstName" Decode.string
```

using this methodology I'm only able to update `firstName` but I want to update complete user data.

> API response is

```
{
firstName : "user",
lastName : "hero",
gender : "male"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Data is defined as

```elm
type alias Data =
    { firstName : String
    , lastName : String
    , gender : String
    }
```

Then you can define your decoder like this:

```
decodeData : Decode.Decoder Data
decodeData = 
    Decode.map3 Data
        (Decode.field "firstName" Decode.string)
        (Decode.field "lastName" Decode.string)
        (Decode.field "gender" Decode.string)
```

Comment: Thanks, Chad Gilbert